# A question about randomization in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, questasim

I am now working on a verilog testbench file and I want to get a random value in my code, but I have found that Questa Sim uses the same seed again and again. I have read through [$random in Verilog doesn't seem to be working](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138497/random-in-verilog-doesnt-seem-to-be-working/138574#138574) and tried typing -sv_seed random in the transcript window, but the program doesn't understand my command. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Reminds me Apple II’s faulty RAND function so we used time of day for a seed

Comment: Just to be sure that you are doing nothing wrong, can you show us some code?

Comment: I have one line:
#0 random_out_delay = $urandom_range(31,0);
but the problem is that I don't know where to input the "-sv_seed random" command

Answer (score 1):

The `-sv_seed random` is an option the to `vsim` command line. By the time you get to vsim's transcript window, it's too late to change the seed.

When invoking Questa from the shell command

```
vsim -sv_seed random ...
```

When starting Questa simulation using the GUI, look for form to fill in vsim options.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If it's too late, what should I do if I want to change the seed before simulation? Where should I type the command "sv_seed random"?

Comment: `vsim -sv_seed random <all_other_arguments>. If you are using the Questa GUI, when you go to "Start Simulation" there is an Other Vsim Options form